# SQL: Select many records into a new table

Tags: sql

I want to select at least 20 records from a table into a new table based on a number 1 to 20.

```
select * into blah from foo where fubar = '1'
```

how do i add 1 to 20 into that statement?

edit:

```
select * into blah from foo where fubar = '1' and where fubar = '2' and where fubar = '3'
```

Sorry. Let me see if i can make it more clear. Basically i want to select 20 record based on fubar = 1 to 20. I tried to use "and where" but i get a syntax error.

eidt: what if fubar is nvarchar(11)

Comment: can you give more details? that 1-20 number - is it in the table?

Comment: SELECT TOP 20 * INTO blah FROM foo WHERE fubar = '1'

Answer (score 6):

*If your first Table name is **"foo"** and the new table name **"blah"***

```
SELECT * INTO blah FROM foo WHERE fubar BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

or

```
SELECT * INTO blah FROM foo WHERE fubar >= 1 AND fubar <=20
```

Comment: +1 for having the same answer as me and not knowing who posted it first.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * INTO blah FROM foo WHERE fubar BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

Comment: I am so mad you got votes for the answer I put first  :( ...
j/k

Comment: @rm:  The OP said "based on a number 1 to 20", so I think this should work for him.

Comment: @tstamper:  I didn't see anyone else with this answer when I posted, I don't know who posted first, but if it was you, I will certainly upvote you and give you credit.  Right now, it says "answered 2 hours ago" for both of us.

Comment: @gpojd-- just making it a sport..nothing serious..having fun with it

Answer (score 1):

Two cheesy methods both involving changing the where clause:

If fubar is a numeric column try where fubar >0 and fubar < 20
if fubar is a character column try where fubar in ('1','2','3', ... '19','20')

I am sure there are more effective methods that are general but this might help you out in a particular circumstance.

Comment: I think your cheesy methods is what i'm looking for. Thank. I'm hold off to see if someone can afford a better statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 20 * into blah from foo where fubar = '1'
```

I'm not really sure what you're asking though.

EDIT:

```
select top 20 * into blah from foo where fubar IN ('1','2',...'20')
```

Answer (score 0):

You looking at just inserting the top 20 records?

```
SELECT TOP 20 *
INTO
    blah
FROM
    foo
WHERE
    fubar = '1'
```

There are also many ways that you can [parameterize the TOP clause](https://web.archive.org/web/20150520123828/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-use-a-variable-in-a-top-clause-in-sql-server.html) too (the examples are for SQL Server).

**EDIT:**

In response to your update, if fubar column is numeric, then it's simply

```
SELECT * INTO blah FROM foo WHERE fubar BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

if fubar is a character field but contains only numbers then you can cast the field to Integer and still use the BETWEEN clause

```
SELECT * INTO blah FROM foo WHERE CAST(fubar AS INT) BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

This is for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

It depends on database you are using.
For MS SQL Server it will be

```
SELECT TOP 20 * into blah from foo order by fubar
```

For Oracle

```
SELECT * into blah from foo  order by fubar where rownum()<=20
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your 'AND" to an 'OR':

```
select * into blah 
from foo 
where fubar = 1 
OR fubar = 2 
OR fubar = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If fubar is really 1 to 20 integer(or other number type), but stored in nvarchar(), then I would use BETWEEN like @TStamper says and as @Russ Cam suggested with the CAST(fubar as Int), if you're in MSSQL or MySQL.

Unlikey what you mean, but...
 if when you say fubar may be an nvarchar, and your really looking to have non-numberical values that are tested, the IN('1','x','5679fjdk', etc...) would probably be needed.